# How to sniffer the passing data through ZMQ

Tags: zeromq

I'm using 2 forms of ZMQ:
- ipc.
- inproc.

Is there any tool (or otherwise how can I do it) to sniffer the data that is passing through the ZMQ (in the 2 forms) ?

Thanks

Comment: It's doubtful you can do what you're looking for, better to just log the data within your app.

Comment: Agreed. If you can clarify what you're trying to accomplish we might be able to help you find another way.